# How to send push notification using NSStream and APN certificate

Tags: ios, macos, apple-push-notifications, nsstream

I know there are tools available to send push notification that are implemented with php or C++ or something else. I am trying develop my own using NSStream. I have tried the following code.

```
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)[website host], 80, &readStream, &writeStream);

    NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
    NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
```

Delegate method:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
NSLog(@"stream:handleEvent: is invoked...");

switch(eventCode) {
    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        // it is getting here
        break;
    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
    {
        if (stream == oStream) {
            NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                @"{"aps":{"alert":"Hello from APN server.","badge":"1"}}"];

            // how do i add device token

            const uint8_t * payload =
                (const uint8_t *)[str UTF8String];
            [oStream write:payload maxLength:strlen(payload)];
            [oStream close];
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Now the problems are:

1. How do I open the stream with a push certificate
2. How do I generate the payload with a device token